# Javafx: Updating a phone number textfield with hashtags and numbers live

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

currently working on a textfield where if you input your number it updates it like:

1##-###-####

12#-###-####

Unfortunately, working on it via console to convert an input "1234" into "123-4##-####" works, though when I push the updated string "123-4##-####" it automatically replaces the cursor section to the beginning where it would constantly replace the first digit. Can someone help out to save the cursor position when updating the string within the textbox? Here's my update code.

```
phoneField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
       Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
       Matcher m = p.matcher(newValue);
       String result = "";
       String finalString = "";
       try {
           while (m.find()) {
               result = m.group();
           }
           int size = result.length();
           for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
               if(i == 3 || i == 6) finalString += "-";
               finalString += result.charAt(i);
           }
           for(int i = size; i < 10; i++) {
               if(i == 3 || i == 6) finalString += "-";
               finalString += "#";
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           finalString = "INVALID NUMBER";
       }
        phoneField.setText(finalString);
    });
```

Comment: Maybe `phoneField. positionCaret(newValue.length())` ?

Comment: Unfortunately that just keeps setting my caret to the end of the text

Comment: @Nom hey, have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a listener, as you’re changing the very property to which you’re listening, which means the listener gets called twice.  In fact, an infinite loop will result, unless the StringProperty is smart enough to refrain from firing a change when the new value is equal to the old value.  (Most JavaBean compliant classes behave that way, but I’m not aware of any guarantee of that behavior.)

For restricting the behavior of a TextField, you usually want to use a [TextFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html):

```
private TextField createPhoneField() {
    TextField phoneField = new TextField();
    phoneField.setPrefColumnCount(12);

    TextFormatter<String> formatter =
        new TextFormatter<>(this::addPhoneNumberMask);
    phoneField.setTextFormatter(formatter);

    return phoneField;
}

private TextFormatter.Change addPhoneNumberMask(
                                TextFormatter.Change change) {

    // Ignore cursor movements, unless the text is empty (in which case
    // we're initializing the field).
    if (!change.isContentChange() &&
        !change.getControlNewText().isEmpty()) {

        return change;
    }

    String text = change.getControlNewText();
    int start = change.getRangeStart();
    int end = change.getRangeEnd();

    int anchor = change.getAnchor();
    int caret = change.getCaretPosition();

    StringBuilder newText = new StringBuilder(text);

    int dash;
    while ((dash = newText.lastIndexOf("-")) >= start) {
        newText.deleteCharAt(dash);
        if (caret > dash) {
            caret--;
        }
        if (anchor > dash) {
            anchor--;
        }
    }

    while (newText.length() < 3) {
        newText.append('#');
    }
    if (newText.length() == 3 || newText.charAt(3) != '-') {
        newText.insert(3, '-');
        if (caret > 3 || (caret == 3 && end <= 3 && change.isDeleted())) {
            caret++;
        }
        if (anchor > 3 || (anchor == 3 && end <= 3 && change.isDeleted())) {
            anchor++;
        }
    }

    while (newText.length() < 7) {
        newText.append('#');
    }
    if (newText.length() == 7 || newText.charAt(7) != '-') {
        newText.insert(7, '-');
        if (caret > 7 || (caret == 7 && end <= 7 && change.isDeleted())) {
            caret++;
        }
        if (anchor > 7 || (anchor == 7 && end <= 7 && change.isDeleted())) {
            anchor++;
        }
    }

    while (newText.length() < 12) {
        newText.append('#');
    }

    if (newText.length() > 12) {
        newText.delete(12, newText.length());
    }

    text = newText.toString();
    anchor = Math.min(anchor, 12);
    caret = Math.min(caret, 12);

    change.setText(text);
    change.setRange(0, change.getControlText().length());
    change.setAnchor(anchor);
    change.setCaretPosition(caret);

    return change;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few changes I've made to your code. 
First of all you should append result of matches in order to get correct value - I've used StringBuilder.append() for it. Then, I've changed compile pattern, otherwise it would not correctly process the input.

```
phoneField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(newValue);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String finalString = "";
    try {
        while (m.find()) {
            result.append(m.group());
        }
        int size = result.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (i == 3 || i == 6) finalString += "-";
            finalString += result.charAt(i);
        }
        for (int i = size; i < 9; i++) {
            if (i == 3 || i == 6) finalString += "-";
            finalString += "#";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        finalString = "INVALID NUMBER";
    }
    phoneField.setText(finalString);
});
```

Note, that probably it's worth adding length check for the field.

Comment: that's outdated (at least since fx8, in some update release like u40 or so, forgot the exact version) and discouraged for reasons outlined in [VGR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42586325/203657) - which also has the appropriate solution :)